# Creating a limited count array of custom type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am creating array of Promises of type [MSGraphScheduleInformation?]. I want to limit the array count to 4, but the repeating param in the API is throwing errors. Below is my code:

**For infinite array count the code looks like this:**

```
var array = [Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>] // This works
```

**For array with limited count:**

```
var array = [Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>](repeating: Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>, count: 4) // Throws error
```

Error I get with above line is - `Cannot convert value of type 'Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>.Type' to expected argument type 'Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>'`

Here is what I want eventually:

```
[Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 1, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 2, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 3, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 4]
```

How do I create an array with count and custom type?

Comment: Are you sure `var array = [Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>]` works? Did you miss a `()` at the end or mistook the `:` for a `=` or anything like that?

Comment: Also, what do you mean you want `Object 1`, `Object 2`, `Object 3` and `Object 4`? What do you want those promises to ***do***? Don't you need to initialise the promise  with a closure that fulfils the promise like `Promise { /* do your thing here */ }`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you are passing a *Type* when an *instance of that Type* is expected.

The `repeating` initialiser of `Array` places the value specified by the `repeating` parameter into the first `count` indices of the array.

It does not, as your question implies you think, create an array whose elements are the *type* specified by the `repeating` array and is limited in size to `count`.

You should also note that `repeating` does not specify an initialiser to be called for each element. It is literally the item that will be placed in each index.

You could say something like

```
var array = [Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]>](repeating: Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]()>, count: 4)
```

You are now passing an instance of a Promise, but you will end up, with *that same instance in the first 4 indices*. :

```
[Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 1, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 1, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 1, 
 Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?] Object 1]
```

(I am ignoring whether `Promise<[MSGraphScheduleInformation?]()>` is even a valid initialiser).

Finally, `count` only specifies the initial size of the array. It isn't an upper or lower limit that somehow applies to the life of the array.  You can remove and append items just like any array.

If you want to limit the number of items in the array you need to do that in your code.

If you want to pre-populate 4 promises, you can use a simple `for` loop, but that doesn't make a lot of sense.  I don't see how you can create a promise before you know what it is promising; I.E. how the promise will be fulfilled.